# Return from parameter and scope

Tags: c++, parameters, scope, error-code

I have a function where I would like to retrieve a string from a function and return an error code:

```
int Connection::RecvMsg(std::string* buffer)
{
  buffer = &RecvBuffer.front();
  RecvBuffer.pop();
  return error_state; 
}
```

I want to pop a string from `RecvBuffer`, and I would like to pass the string tbrough the parameter.

I realized buffer would be invalid after pop. Is the only way to declare a static string inside that function? Are any better ways I should go about it?

Comment: You could std::move the contents of the RecvBuffer.front() into the string pointed by buffer and then pop without any concerns.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might want something more like this:

```
*buffer = RecvBuffer.front();
```

This will assign the string to whatever `buffer` points to.

Comment: Ah, ops! Somehow I forgotten about dereferencing it and copy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to propagate errors in C++ is to use exceptions mechanism.

If you by some reason don't want to use exceptions you can pass information back to the caller using reference.

```
int Connection::RecvMsg(std::string &buffer)
{
    buffer = RecvBuffer.front();
    RecvBuffer.pop();
    return error_state; 
}
```

Of course, you can use pointers as well but in this case it is better to make sure that caller is not passing nullptr. So you need to write something like this

```
int Connection::RecvMsg(std::string *buffer)
{
    error_state = false;

    if(buffer != nullptr)
    {
        *buffer = RecvBuffer.front();
        RecvBuffer.pop();
        error_state = true;
    }

    return error_state; 
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Initially I passed by reference and had the first example. But isn't that assigning an address?. - EDIT - Ops, I just remembered the rules of reference variables. Yes that's a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Outparameters are not the only (and IMO not the best) choice to model several parameters. Instead, I would propose returning both values in a `pair`:

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>

std::pair<std::string,int> Connection::RecvMsg() {
  if (recvBuffer.empty()) {
    return std::make_pair<std::string,int>(std::string(),error_code);
  }
  std::string const front = recvBuffer.front();
  recvBuffer.pop();
  return std::make_pair<std::string,int>(front,no_error);
}
```